# Binary to text conversion program not working

Tags: c

I am trying to write a c program to convert a binary file to text. The format of the binary file is as follows:
First there is an integer followed by a character that is either 'i' or 'd'. For example "5i". I am trying to read it but I am getting the following values:

```
-4

-3

-2

-1

0

1

2

3

4
```

My code is as follows:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void BinaryToText(char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  BinaryToText(argv[1], argv[2]);
}

void BinaryToText(char *inputFile, char *outputFile) {
    //unsigned int num;  // assuming 32 bit ints
    int i, len;

    FILE *finp = fopen(inputFile, "rb");
    FILE *fout = fopen(outputFile, "w");
    int key;
    char operation[1];
    while ((fread(&key, sizeof(int), 1, finp) == 1)) {
        fread(&operation, sizeof(char), 1, finp);
        fprintf(fout, "%d\n", key);
        fprintf(fout, "%c\n", operation);
    }
    fclose(finp);
    fclose(fout);
}``` 
Any help would be appreciated
````

Comment: If you upload a test file on pastebin or something like that it'll be easier to help you out

Comment: As in the input and required output files? or the code itself?

Comment: An input file and the expected output. The easier it is for someone to just copy-paste your code and run it, the higher the chances to get an answer

Comment: operation is an array of one char, so passing &operation to fread is not good . Just do fread(operation,...) . For printf use operation[0].

Comment: Here is the pastebin with the input and the required/correct output https://pastebin.com/UpBrdCyk

Comment: @PtitXav I changed it to operation instead of &operation and instead of an i it's reading the character as 'k'

Comment: It worked using @PtitXav suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: General advice: `fopen` can fail and you need to check that. `fopen` is probably even the operation that fails most mostly because the file you try to open doesn't exist.